# Not able to Configure relay sentry setup with proxy

Tags: sentry

I want to connect relay to sentry.io via proxy service/application.
Please help me in this I am not able to find any way to put proxy between relay and sentry.

Config.yml
relay:
mode: managed
upstream: “https://sentry.io/”
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
tls_port: ~
tls_identity_path: ~
tls_identity_password: ~

Where I have to set the proxy in relay?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the upstream location to your proxy service/application and there you need to have another relay which can upload the data to sentry.io

Warn : This will just forward the messages, so configure your first relay in proxy mode.